# Counting and collating html table values

Tags: php, mysql, html

I have a form which generates an HTML table using a PHP script on submission.

If the table looks like this...

```
Qty | Colour | Size  | Name
----------------------------------
10  | Red    | Small | Name 1
5   | Red    | Small | Name 2
25  | White  | Large | Name 3
```

...I'd like it to give information like this:

```
15 Red Small
25 White Large
```

Is this even possible as it stands using some clever PHP method I'm yet to learn? If not, and I were to use a database, would it be possible? I'd like to avoid using a database if at all possible as I don't have database capabilities on the site it needs to be deployed on but could put it on another domain if need be.

Apologies for the lack of research effort on this one, I'm not sure where to start.

-- edit to add code --

HTML

```
<form action="processform.php" method="post" id="monogramming-builder">
  <fieldset>
    <table>
      <tr>
        <th>Qty</th>
        <th>Colour</th>
        <th>Size</th>
        <th>Name</th>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td><input type="text" name="qty[]" class="qty" /></td>
        <td>
          <select name="colour[]">
            <option value="">[Please Select]</option>
            <option value="Red">Red</option>
            <option value="Black">Black</option>
            <option value="White">White</option>
          </select>
        </td>
        <td>
          <select name="size[]">
            <option value="">[Please Select]</option>
            <option value="Small">Small</option>
            <option value="Medium">Medium</option>
            <option value="Large">Large</option>
            <option value="XL">XL</option>
            <option value="2XL">2XL</option>
          </select>
        </td>
        <td><input type="text" name="name[]" maxlength="18" /></td>
      </tr>
    </table>
    <p><a href="javascript:;" class="addrow">Add a row</a></p>    
    <input type="submit" value="Send Request" />
  </fieldset>
</form>
```

PHP:

```
$qtys = $_POST['qty'];
$colours = $_POST['colour'];
$sizes = $_POST['size'];
$names = $_POST['name'];

$output = '<h2>You have requested:</h2>' . "\n";
$output .= '<table><tr><th>Qty</th><th>Colour</th><th>Size</th><th>Name</th></tr>' . "\n";
for($i=0, $count = count($qtys); $i < $count; $i++) {
  $output .= '<tr>';
  $output .= '<td>' . $qtys[$i] . '</td>' . "\n"; 
  $output .= '<td>' . $colours[$i] . '</td>' . "\n";
  $output .= '<td>' . $sizes[$i] . '</td>' . "\n";
  $output .= '<td>' . $names[$i] . '</td>' . "\n";
  $output .= '</tr>' . "\n";   
}
$output .= '</table>';  
echo $output;
```

JS

```
$('.addrow').click(function(){
    var tablerow = '<tr><td><input type="text" name="qty[]" class="qty" /></td><td><select name="colour[]"><option value="">[Please Select]</option><option value="Red">Red</option><option value="Black">Black</option><option value="White">White</option></select></td><td><select name="size[]"><option value="">[Please Select]</option><option value="Small">Small</option><option value="Medium">Medium</option><option value="Large">Large</option><option value="XL">XL</option><option value="2XL">2XL</option></select></td><td><input type="text" name="name[]" maxlength="18" /></td></tr>';
    $('tr:last-child').after(tablerow);
  });
```

Comment: In what form do you have your table? PHP array or final HTML markup?

Comment: @SergioTulentsev It generates an HTML table through a for loop via PHP arrays

Comment: @Sabari HTML & PHP code pasted

Comment: Whats your js code for add row. There is no function calling at all

Comment: @Sabari Oh, sorry. Little bit of jQuery added for you. Might be useful: CDN is `<script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.1/jquery.min.js"></script>` if you're rebuilding this for yourself.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think this code or something very similar will do what you want:

```
$qtys = $_POST['qty'];
$colours = $_POST['colour'];
$sizes = $_POST['size'];
$names = $_POST['name'];

$totals = Array();

$output = '<h2>You have requested:</h2>' . "\n";
$output .= '<table><tr><th>Qty</th><th>Colour</th><th>Size</th><th>Name</th></tr>' . "\n";
for($i=0, $count = count($qtys); $i < $count; $i++) {
  // if we've not seen this colour before, set up an empty array
  if(!array_key_exists($colours[$i], $totals)) {
    $totals[$colours[$i]] = Array();
  }
  // if we've not seen this size for this colour before, set it to zero
  if(!array_key_exists($sizes[$i], $totals[$colours[$i]])) {
    $totals[$colours[$i]][$sizes[$i]] = 0;
  }
  // Add to the quantity for this colour/size
  $totals[$colours[$i]][$sizes[$i]] += $qtys[$i];

  $output .= '<tr>';
  $output .= '<td>' . $qtys[$i] . '</td>' . "\n"; 
  $output .= '<td>' . $colours[$i] . '</td>' . "\n";
  $output .= '<td>' . $sizes[$i] . '</td>' . "\n";
  $output .= '<td>' . $names[$i] . '</td>' . "\n";
  $output .= '</tr>' . "\n";   
}
$output .= '</table>';  
echo $output;


$output = "<table>";
foreach($totals as $color=>$totals_by_size) {
  foreach($totals_by_size as $size=>$quantity) {
    $output .= '<tr>';
    $output .= '<td>'.$color.'</td>';
    $output .= '<td>'.$size.'</td>';
    $output .= '<td>'.$quantity.'</td>';
    $output .= '</tr>';
  }
}
echo $output.'</table>';
```

What we do is while you're looping over the post data to build the first table, we're building a multi-dimensional array that looks like this:

```
array(2) {
  ["red"]=>
  array(1) {
    ["Small"]=>
    int(15)
  }
  ["white"]=>
  array(1) {
    ["large"]=>
    int(25)
  }
}
```

Then we loop over that array and build another table to display it.

Comment: Thanks for your help. Just tried this but it's giving a blank screen. Just having a look at it to see where it's dropping out.

Comment: Just submitted an edit for this, there was a `=` and a couple of `)` missing. Other than that, brilliant, thanks so much for your help.

Comment: One doubt here. If color and size matches its ok. Then what if the names are different. Then it should be two different records right

Comment: No, it's simply a collation of colour and size, your code does exactly what I was after.

Comment: Yeah I thought there'd be a few syntax errors, thanks for correcting. Glad to be of help! - @Sabari if it was split by name as well then it would be the same as the original table!

Comment: @HowardYeend I just thought of another approach of splitting all records and combining all records with same attributes. No it will be different, in the shown table he had added only one record for each name. If he adds two record with same name and other attributes same it will show as two different rows

Comment: @Sabari Oh I understand - yes that's a nice approach.

Comment: @HowardYeend Quick (maybe) question, how would I structure the nested foreach loops if I was to add another field to the form, namely 'garment'? It would be sent as an array like the others.

Comment: you'd need to add another chunk of code in the loop for totalling, eg `  if(!array_key_exists($garments[$i], $totals[$colours[$i]][$sizes[i]])) {
    $totals[$colours[$i]][$sizes[$i]][$garments[$i]] = 0;
  }
` and then add a few lines to the foreach: `foreach($totals_by_size as $size=>$totals_by_size_garment) { foreach($totals_by_size_garment as $garment=>$quantity) {` and then just add another row to the table: `$output .= '<td>'.$garment.'</td>';` - I think.

Comment: Brill, thanks. I'll give that a whirl as soon as I get the chance. Sometimes some people deserve more than 1 upvote and a tick for their answer!

Answer (score 0):

Answer is posted. Anyway i have tried. You can try this one:

```
$qtys = $_POST['qty'];
$colours = $_POST['colour'];
$sizes = $_POST['size'];
$names = $_POST['name'];
$product = array();


for($i=0, $count = count($qtys); $i < $count; $i++) {
    if (!isset($product[$colours[$i]][$sizes[$i]][$names[$i]])) {
        $product[$colours[$i]][$sizes[$i]][$names[$i]] = $qtys[$i];
    } else {
        $product[$colours[$i]][$sizes[$i]][$names[$i]] = $product[$colours[$i]][$sizes[$i]][$names[$i]] + $qtys[$i];
    }
}

$output = '';
$output .= '<h2>You have requested:</h2>' . "\n";
$output .= '<table><tr><th>Qty</th><th>Colour</th><th>Size</th><th>Name</th></tr>' . "\n";
foreach ($product as $product_keys => $product_values) {
    foreach ($product_values as $product_key => $product_value) {
        foreach ($product_value as $new_product_key => $new_product_value) {
              $output .= '<tr>';
                $output .= '<td>' . $new_product_value . '</td>' . "\n"; 
                $output .= '<td>' . $product_keys . '</td>' . "\n";
                $output .= '<td>' . $product_key . '</td>' . "\n";
                $output .= '<td>' . $new_product_key . '</td>' . "\n";
              $output .= '</tr>' . "\n"; 
        }

    }
}
$output .= '</table>';  
echo $output;
```

Hope this helps you :)

Comment: Thanks for this, interesting to see the two different approaches. You've collated according to name as well which isn't necessary for this case but this may very well come in useful in the future. Thanks a lot!